# establecer propiedad pattern de HTML via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

buen dia.
tengo un formulario PHP con un select y un input en HTML, el select con id= idTipoDocumento tiene tres opciones: ID, Pasaporte, Carné.

```
div class="col-sm-4"><label>Tipo de documento de identidad</label><select class="form-control input-sm" id="idTipoDocumento" name = "nTipoDocumento">
                <option value="ID">ID</option>
                <option value="CARNÉ DE RESIDENTE">Carné de Residente</option>
                <option value="PASAPORTE">Pasaporte</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

si el usuario selecciona ID entonces via jQuery establezco el pattern del input HTML con id= idDocumento asi:

```
$('#idTipoDocumento').on('change', function () {
        var documento = $(this).val();
        if(documento=="ID")
        {
        $('#idDocumento').attr("pattern", '[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1}');
        $('#idDocumento').attr("placeholder", "FORMATO DUI ########-#");
        }
```

y me funciona, el problema viene que cuando el usuario seleccione Pasaporte o carne entonces quiero que el input no tenga ningun pattern establecido, de momento utilizo esto pero no me funciona

```
$('#idTipoDocumento').on('change', function () {
        var documento = $(this).val();
        if(documento=="DUI")
        {
        $('#idDocumento').attr("pattern", '[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1}');
        $('#idDocumento').attr("placeholder", "FORMATO DUI ########-#");
        }

        if(documento=="CARNET DE RESIDENTE")
        {
        $('#idDocumento').removeAttr("pattern");
        $('#idDocumento').attr("placeholder", "");
        }

        if(documento=="PASAPORTE")
        {
        $('#idDocumento').removeAttr("pattern");
        $('#idDocumento').attr("placeholder", "");
        }

        });
```

Podrían ayudarme?

el código del input es el siguiente

```
<div class="col-sm-4"><label>Número de documento de identidad *</label><input type="text" title="especifique número de documento" id="idDocumento" name = "nDocumento"class="form-control" autofocus required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Debe ingresar número de documento válido')" oninput="setCustomValidity('validar valor')"></div>
```

Comment: No te funciona porque el valor es "CARNÉ DE RESIDENTE" y no "CARNET DE RESIDENTE"

Answer (score 0):

Tienes código de más, simplificando te dejo como funcionaría lo que necesitas

```js
$(function() {
  $('#idTipoDocumento').on('change', function() {
    var documento = $(this).val();
    if (documento == "ID") {
      $('#idDocumento').attr("pattern", '[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{1}');
      $('#idDocumento').attr("placeholder", "FORMATO DUI ########-#");
    } else {
      $('#idDocumento').removeAttr("pattern");
      $('#idDocumento').attr("placeholder", "");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <label>Tipo de documento de identidad</label>
    <select id="idTipoDocumento" name="nTipoDocumento">
    <option value="ID">ID</option>
    <option value="CARNEDERESIDENTE">Carné de Residente</option>
    <option value="PASAPORTE">Pasaporte</option>
  </select>
    <input id="idDocumento">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias, pero al agregar un numero de ID valido, por ejemplo 12345678-9 según el patron establecido, siempre me muestra un mensaje de error el input, podrías ayudarme? actualizo y te dejo el codigo del input en la pregunta

Comment: @PabloTobar entiendo pero tendrías que añadir como funciona `setCustomValidity`

Comment: si, pero setCustomValidity solo muestra el mensaje "validar algo"